# Get timeslots based on given data and time

Tags: javascript

I want timeslots based on the given date and start times and end times.

**Input is like this:**

this is **stat time** and **end times** list

```
[ 
    {
        "StartTime" : "10:00",
        "endTime" : "14:00"
    },
    {
        "StartTime" : "16:00",
        "endTime" : "18:00"
    }
]
```

**additional data:**

```
"SlotDuration": 60 //in minutes
"minStartTimeDufference": 15 // in minutes
```

then the **output** is like

```
 [
    "10:00-11:00",
    "10:15-11:15",
    "10:30-11:30",
    "10:45-11:45",
    "11:00-12:00",
    "11:15-12:15",
    "11:30-12:30",
    "11:45-12:45",
    "12:00-13:00",
    "12:15-13:15",
    "12:30-13:30",
    "12:45-13:45",
    "13:00-14:00",
    "16:00-17:00",
    "16:15-17:15",
    "16:30-17:30",
    "16:45-17:45",
    "17:00-18:00"
]
```

**minSlotDuration** is slot duration from start time to end time AND **minStartTimeDufference** is time to consider for making slots, we can say its duration also. Get more idea by viewing the output.

**What I tried:**

```js
let parseTime = (s) => {
  let c = s.split(':');
  return parseInt(c[0]) * 60 + parseInt(c[1]);
}

let convertHours = (mins) => {
  let hour = Math.floor(mins / 60);
  mins = mins % 60;
  let converted = pad(hour, 2) + ':' + pad(mins, 2);
  return converted;
}

let pad = (str, max) => {
  str = str.toString();
  return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
}

let calculate_time_slot = (start_time, end_time, interval) => {
  let i, formatted_time;
  let time_slots = new Array();
  for (let i = start_time; i <= end_time; i = i + interval) {
    formatted_time = convertHours(i);
    time_slots.push(formatted_time);
  }
  return time_slots;
}

let date = "20-07-2019"
let startTime = "10:00";
let endTime = "14:00";
let interval = 60; // in minutes
start_time = parseTime(startTime)
end_time = parseTime(endTime)
let times_ara = calculate_time_slot(start_time, end_time, interval);

console.log(times_ara);
```

Comment: In your example, what determines the maximum length of time for a slot?

Comment: @OliverRadini SlotDuration is the max time slot length

Comment: There's an error in the output after `"16:15-17:15"`. Should the remaining half an hour slot `17:30-18:00` considered or should that be ignored since it doesn't last an hour?

Comment: @adiga it should be ignored because timeslot duration is only 60 minutes not less than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

**Demo:**

```js
var input = [ 
    {
        "StartTime" : "10:00",
        "endTime" : "14:00"
    },
    {
        "StartTime" : "16:00",
        "endTime" : "18:00"
    }
];

var slotDuration = 60; //in minutes
var minStartTimeDufference = 15; // in minutes

class Time {
  constructor(time) {
    if (time) {
      this.hour = parseInt(time.split(':')[0]);
      this.minute = parseInt(time.split(':')[1]);
    }
  }
  addMinute(minute) {
    this.minute += minute;
    if (this.minute >= 60) {
      this.minute -= 60;
      this.hour += 1;
    }
  }
  isBefore(time) {
    if (this.hour < time.hour) return true;
    else if (this.hour == time.hour && this.minute <= time.minute) return true;
    return false;
  }
  
  toText() {
    let result = '';
    if (this.hour < 10) result += `0${this.hour}:`;
    else result += `${this.hour}:`;
    if (this.minute < 10) result += `0${this.minute}`;
    else result += `${this.minute}`;
    return result;
  }
}

var result = [];
input.forEach((val) => {
  let start = new Time(val.StartTime);
  let end = new Time(val.endTime);
  let temp = new Time(val.StartTime);
  temp.addMinute(slotDuration);
  while (temp.isBefore(end)) {
    result.push(`${start.toText()}-${temp.toText()}`);
    start.addMinute(minStartTimeDufference);
    temp.addMinute(minStartTimeDufference);
  }
})
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Can be simplified with loop from start minutes to end minutes minus SlotDuration :

```js
var SlotDuration = 60, minStartTimeDufference = 15, result = []
var data = [ { StartTime: "10:00", endTime: "14:00" }, 
             { StartTime: "16:00", endTime: "18:00" } ]

const getMinutes = s => s.slice(0, 2) * 60 + +s.slice(-2)
const getTime = m => new Date(m * 6e4).toJSON().slice(11, 16)

for (var item of data) {
  var start = getMinutes(item.StartTime), end = getMinutes(item.endTime);

  for (var m = start; m <= end - SlotDuration; m += minStartTimeDufference) 
    result.push(getTime(m) + '-' + getTime(m + SlotDuration))
}

console.log( result )
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Date.UTC()`

> Date.UTC(year[, month[, day[, hour[, minute[, second[,
>   millisecond]]]]]])

```js
const range = (start, end, dur = 60, diff = 15) => {
  start = parse(start)
  end = parse(end)
  
  let sd = new Date(Date.UTC(2000, 0, 1, start[0], start[1]))
  let ed = Date.parse(new Date(Date.UTC(2000, 0, 1, end[0], end[1])))
  let td = new Date(sd)

  while (Date.parse(td) < ed) {
    td = new Date(sd)
    td.setUTCMinutes(td.getUTCMinutes() + dur)
    console.log(
      format(sd.getUTCHours(), sd.getUTCMinutes()) + '-' +
      format(td.getUTCHours(), td.getUTCMinutes())
    )
    sd.setUTCMinutes(sd.getUTCMinutes() + diff)
  }
}

const format = (hh, mm) => {
  return hh.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + mm.toString().padStart(2, '0')
}

const parse = (time) => {
  return time.split(':').map(Number)
}

range("10:00", "18:00", 60, 15)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%!important;
}
```

Comment: Hello, My friend needs help with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57141561/7820923) can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Updated your code without considering the minimum difference between start times.

```
let calculate_time_slot = (start_time, end_time, interval) => {
    let i, formatted_time;
    let time_slots = new Array();
    for (let i = start_time; i + interval <= end_time; i = i + interval) {
        formatted_time = convertHours(i) + "-" + convertHours(i + interval);
        time_slots.push(formatted_time);
    }
    return time_slots;
}
```

If you want to add minimum difference between start times, change `i = i + interval` to `i = i + minStartDifference`