# Identify Booked time slots from generated time slots with maintenance time and generated new slots

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have slots generated based on the start time and end time. Now I want to identify slots form generated slots that are already booked. Additionally, I also want to identify slots based on booked slots and maintenance time. maintenance time is additional time after the booking is done. when slots new slots are generated after someone's booking then next slot will be generated based on that time.

**Example:**

**Input:**

Actual time slots:

```
[ '10:00-10:30',
  '10:30-11:00',
  '11:00-11:30',
  '11:30-12:00',
  '12:00-12:30',
  '12:30-13:00',
  '13:00-13:30',
  '13:30-14:00',
  '14:00-14:30',
  '14:30-15:00',
  '15:00-15:30',
  '15:30-16:00'
]
```

if Booked Time Slots is `["11:00-13:00","14:15-15:15"]`, Maintenance time is `15 mins` then the output should be:

```
[{
        "slot": "10:00-10:30",
        "isBooked": false
    },
    {
        "slot": "10:30-11:00",
        "isBooked": false
    },
    {
        "slot": "11:00-11:30",
        "isBooked": true
    },
    {
        "slot": "11:30-12:00",
        "isBooked": true
    },
    {
        "slot": "12:00-12:30",
        "isBooked": true
    },
    {
        "slot": "12:30-13:00",
        "isBooked": true
    },
    {
        "slot": "13:15-13:45",
        "isBooked": false
    },
    {
        "slot": "13:45-14:15",
        "isBooked": true
    },
    {
        "slot": "14:15-14:45",
        "isBooked": true
    },
    {
        "slot": "14:45-15:15",
        "isBooked": true
    },
    {
        "slot": "15:30-16:00",
        "isBooked": false
    }]
```

let's make it simple

//Booking start time 10:00, booking end time = 16:00

```
[ '10:00-11:00',
  '11:00-12:00',
  '12:00-13:00',
  '13:00-14:00',
  '14:00-15:00',
  '15:00-16:00'
]
```

if Booked Time Slots is **["11:00-13:00"]**, Maintenance time is **15 mins** then the output should be:

```
[{
    "slot": "10:00-11:00",
    "isBooked": false
}
{
    "slot": "11:00-12:00",
    "isBooked": true
},
{
    "slot": "12:00-13:00",
    "isBooked": true
},{
    "slot": "13:15-14:15",
    "isBooked": false
},{
    "slot": "14:15-15:15",
    "isBooked": false
}]
```

Now here I cant generate slot from **"15:15-16:15"** because my last slot end time is of **16:00**

I have tried this:

```js
const ts = [
  "10:00-10:30",
  "10:30-11:00",
  "11:00-11:30",
  "11:30-12:00",
  "12:00-12:30",
  "12:30-13:00",
  "13:00-13:30",
  "13:30-14:00",
  "14:00-14:30",
  "14:30-15:00",
  "15:00-15:30",
  "15:30-16:00"
];

const avail = (ts, booked) =>
  ts.map(item => {
      const[start, end] = item.split('-');
      const isBooked = booked
          .map(item => item.split('-'))
          .some(([bookedStart, bookedEnd]) =>
              (start >= bookedStart && start < bookedEnd) ||
              (end > bookedStart && end <= bookedEnd) ||
              (bookedStart >= start && bookedStart < end));
      return {slot: `${start}-${end}`, isBooked};
  })

console.log(avail(ts, ["11:00-13:00", "14:00-15:30"]));
```

but it's not working for all the cases,

Comment: can you provide all/more test cases ?

Comment: @ShubhanuSharma Please find my edited code

Comment: Is your timeslots always in 30 min duration? Or is it dynamic?

Comment: @PsyGik It's dynamic,  I am passing variable as in mins while generating slots.

Comment: Can I get some assumptions? Say, is the start time always fixed? You mentioned the duration is dynamic so that means there has to be a fixed end time as well, correct?

Comment: @PsyGik absolutely.

Comment: @Dweep : In your first test case, slot '15:30-16:00' should **NOT** be booked, based on your logic (30 min descretion, 15 min maintenance time). Or am I missing something?

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg Sorry my bad, Corrected now.

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg any updates?

Comment: are you forced to generate all timeslots first? or is it possible to find out all "free" time ranges first and then slice them into slots?

Comment: @skyboyer you can choose second option as well. It's not necessary to generate timeslots at the first.

Comment: Does this question imply you store those slot in some DB, otherwise how you know those that are always "booked" ?I mean that label could change dynamically. I believe this question then is too generic