# Reactjs fetch data from firestore when click button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, loaddata

I want to load data from firestore when user click `handleReset()`. When i click `handleReset()` it should load data from firestore and store in localstorage. I'm using reactjs. Error message `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

**admin.js**

```js
  handleReset(e) {
    const products = getDefaultProducts();
    saveProducts(products);
    this.setState({products});
    alert('Product Reset');
  }
```

**product.js**

```js
export const getDefaultProducts = () => {

  const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('vouchers').doc('default');
  console.log('ref', ref)
    ref.get().then((doc) => {

      if (doc.exists) {
        return [
          { id: 'v5', qty: doc.data().v5 }, 
          { id: 'v10', qty: doc.data().v10, }, 
          { id: 'v20', qty: doc.data().v20 }, 
          { id: 'v50', qty: doc.data().v50 }, 
          { id: 'v100', qty: doc.data().v100 }
        ];  
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    });
}

export const saveProducts = (products) => {
  products = products.map(prd => {
    prd.qty = isNaN(+prd.qty) ? 0 : prd.qty
    return prd;
  });

  localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(products));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your error message. `products` object is undefined because you are not returning anything from `getDefaultProducts`. The `ref.get().then(...` is a promise, so that inner function (where you return) is being executed later after your function has completed.

To fix this, in `getDefaultProducts` you must return a Promise, and then use the appropriate `.then` method to access the results.

```
const getDefaultProducts = () => {
    const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('vouchers').doc('default');
    console.log('ref', ref);
    // see we've added a return statement here, to return a Promise from this method
    return ref.get().then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
            return [
                { id: 'v5', qty: doc.data().v5 },
                { id: 'v10', qty: doc.data().v10, },
                { id: 'v20', qty: doc.data().v20 },
                { id: 'v50', qty: doc.data().v50 },
                { id: 'v100', qty: doc.data().v100 }
            ];
        } else {
            throw new Error("No such document!"); // throw error here to cause current promise to be rejected
        }
    });
}

function handleReset(e) {
    getDefaultProducts().then((products) => {
        saveProducts(products);
        this.setState({ products });
        alert('Product Reset');
    }, (err) => {
        // this will be executed if firestore returns an error or document doesn't exist
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello, needs help with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57141561/7820923) can you help?

Comment: Thanks @caesay. Working like charm